# how to tell if a div is height constrained?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know using jquery if a div is height constrained or not.

For example this div is constrained to 100px, whatever the size of the content the div will have 100px height:

```
    <div style="height: 100px;">
         bla bla
    </div>
```

and this one is not constrained and will take the height of it's content :

```
    <div>
          bla bla
    </div>
```

in other words I want to know if the height was set (and what if so) either by setting the style attribute or with a separate css style.
Thanks

**Solution for FF3.6 FF5 IE8 Chrome12 and Opera11 :**

```
function css(a){
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;
  var o={};
  var name;
  var i=0;
  while (i<sheets.length) {
    var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
    var r=0;
    while(r<rules.length) {
          if(typeof(rules[r].style)!="undefined" &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":before") &&   // fix for FF3.6
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":after") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":link") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":hover") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":active") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":visited") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":first-letter") &&
             !rules[r].selectorText.match(":-moz-focus-inner") &&
              a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
              o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
          }
        r++;  
      }
    i++;
  }
  return o;
}

function css2json(css){
  var s = {};
  if(!css) return s;

  var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;

  if (isMSIE)
      {
        if(typeof(css)=="object")
          {
            for(var i in css) {
              if(i.toLowerCase) 
                s[i.toLowerCase()] = css[i];
            }
          }
        else if(typeof css == "string")
          {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
              var l = css[i].split(": ");
              s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
          }
      }
    else
      {
        if(css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration)
          {
            for(var i in css) {
              if((css[i]).toLowerCase)
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
          }
        else if(typeof css == "string")
          {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
              var l = css[i].split(": ");
              s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
          }              
      }
  return s;
}



...           
alert(css($('some selector')).height);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the functions provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517), you can access the height of the element like this:

```
css($('div')).height
```

Those functions account for both inline and inherited styles, which I believe is what you want.  In the event that the height has not been explicitly specified, the `height` property of the returned object will be *`undefined`*.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/sCwAu/)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but that didn't work in my browser (Firefox 3.6). I get: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: before

Comment: @Ariel: Me neither mate.  `before` isn't mentioned in the code, maybe it's a jQuery thing...

Comment: @Pascal COURTOIS: so it doesn't.  It still discovers the properties but the object that's returned from `css()` in IE is malformed. Should be fixable...

Comment: @Town 'before' is the css selector ':before' . jQuery has a bug with :before, :after and a few others when run on FF 3.6

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no direct way to know if a height has been set on an element or not.

However, searching around I came across an idea that I think will work well.

It basically involves cloning the element you want to know about, adding a class to the clone that has a height set to a value that is unlikely to ever be used, and then testing against that.

Here's a method I just put together to test this:

```
function IsHeightSet(id)
{
    var clone = $(id).clone();
    clone.addClass('magicHeight');

    return (clone.height() == 1069)? false : true;
}
```

and the CSS class for magicHeight:

```
.magicHeight
{
    height: 1069px;
}
```

We can then use this to test whether a given element had a height specified or not.

Here's a working example of this code: http://jsfiddle.net/mnpey/1/

Comment: Your answer is interesting since it tells if a div is constrained or not, but it doesn't tell to what it is constrained. But I keep the trick in mind. Thanks.

Comment: I get true for the first one and false for the second. Interesting. What Browser?